# SSH Keys don't work despite SELinux disabled, keys copied and permissions set

Tags: networking, ssh, security

SSH Keys are broken and I've read many threads trying to fix this. Any advice?

I've masked possibly sensitive information such as the IP addresses and SSH keys with [REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS], [LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS] and XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

## ON LOCAL MACHINE

SELinux is off

```
getenforce Disabled
sestatus 
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

**STANDARD KEY TRANSFER**

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' 
ssh jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] "chmod 700 .ssh; > chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys" 
ssh jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] "chmod > 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys" 
ssh jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS]
```

FAILED.  It still asks for a password.  Made multiple attempts.

I did this and it didn't help:

```
ssh-agent bash 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**ALSTERNATIVE KEY TRANSFER**

```
ssh-copy-id -i jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] 
ssh jnowacki@[REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] ssh 'jnowacki@11.22.81.50'
```

FAIL: ASKS FOR PASSWORD

**LOCAL SERVER SSH KEY PERMISSIONS**

```
ls -ltrh ~/.ssh/  | awk '{print $1 "\t" $9}' 
-rw-r--r--      id_rsa.pub
-rw-------      id_rsa
-rw-------      known_hosts.old
-rw-------      known_hosts
-rw-r-----      authorized_keys
```

**REMOTE MACHINE**

I ran this
    ssh-agent bash 
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

**LOCAL SERVER SSH KEY PERMISSIONS**

```
ls -ltrh ~/.ssh/  | awk '{print $1 "\t" $9}'
-rw-r--r--      id_rsa.pub
-rw-------      id_rsa
-rw-------      known_hosts.old
-rw-------      known_hosts
-rw-r-----      authorized_keys
```

Each time checked to make sure only 1 key is in the files.

```
cat authorized_keys  | grep ssh-rsa | wc -l 
1

cat id_rsa.pub  | grep ssh-rsa | wc -l 
1
```

**DEBUGGING on REMOTE SERVER**

```
root@Ubuntu-Z800F:/etc/ssh# /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3Connection from [LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS] port 41850 on [REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS] port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 105/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user jnowacki service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "jnowacki"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "[LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS]"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
```

It then asks for a password on local server.  This is the last line I see. Screenshot provided for proof.

[Last Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgY1r.jpg)

**SSH -VV ON LOCAL SERVER**

```
ssh -vv -p 2222 jnowacki@[REMOTE_SERVER]
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [LOCAL_SERVER} [[LOCAL_SERVER}] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 159/320
debug2: bits set: 1030/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host '[LOCAL_SERVER}' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug2: bits set: 1008/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
jnowacki@[LOCAL_SERVER}'s password:
```

Comment: Can you also include the client output with ssh -vv (extra verbose logging)? Pay attention to messages like “offering key”, and if they don’t appear, it means the client isn’t trying key based authentication.

Comment: Please post the rest of the ssh server debug log.

Comment: Yes, the server debug messages you've posted indicate that the **host key** verification (between remote `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key` and local `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) works fine. The **authentication keys** would be attempted in the next 25 or so lines **after** the `debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"`  message, so you've cut off the debug log just short of the relevant part.

Comment: The server debug log is complete. THat's where it stops and then asks for a password. I've added a ssh -vv log at the bottom of the post. I've also added a screenshot of the log that people think is incomplete to prove that's all that's available. I can't comment yet as this is a new account. So posting a response here.

Comment: And please post your sshd configuration as well.

Comment: In addition to the rest of the debug log (i.e. the part showing the authentication issues) and sshd config, look for the sshd logs on the remote server. They can be in `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` depending on how your syslog is setup.Quite often they will contain enough information to explain the issue.

Comment: Also check the lines containing `IdentityFile` `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the local machine.

Comment: In any case, disabling SELinux is a bad way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line

> debug1: identity file /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_**d**sa

indicates that your ssh client is only finding and using  a **d**sa key, where all your other commands refer to **r**sa keys.

Since OpenSSH 7.0 the dss (dsa) algorithm is disabled by default <sup>[1](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html)</sup>  (which I think the subsequent debugging lines hint at):

> debug1: Trying private key: /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_**d**sa
>   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method

So IMHO that explains why you can't log on, but as to why that happens... I can't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to type this command:

`vim /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

And then activate id_rsa by un-commenting it.  Thank you so much guys!  You are awesome!

Broken:

```
 # IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
 # IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Working:

```
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Key error in log file:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bckadm/nowackj1/.ssh/id_dsa debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```